# A limit and a Riemann

Tags: calculus

Can someone explain to me how i can solve this:

For some value of $a$ the expression $n^a \sum_{k = 1}^{n} k^{3/2}$ has a limit the is non-zero when $n \to \infty$. Determine the value of $a$ and the limit when $n \to \infty$. Hint: review Riemann sums.

So obviously i tried to form a connection between the problem and a Riemann sum. My first thought was that this can be rewritten as an integral, but i don't how the limits. Then i thought $n$ usually have the form $n^{-1}$, which gives $a = -1$, and i got $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n} k^{3/2}}{n}$. And then i thought, it might be a geometric sum. But im not sure it is. Can someone help me?
This is an introductory course so it shouldn't be something too advanced.

Thank you!

Comment: "This can be rewritten as an integral but I don't know the limits" - Hint: Try to write $\int_0^n x^{\frac{3}{2}} dx$ as the limit of riemann sum with intervals $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=-\frac{3}{2}-1+b$ for some real number $b$.

Then your sum is $S_n=n^b \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \big(\frac{k}{n}\big)^\frac{3}{2}$.

Now think of the function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x^\frac{3}{2}$. It is clearly integrable and $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\frac{2}{5}$. The quantity $n^{-b}S_n$ is the (upper) Riemann sum for this function corresponding to the equidistant partition of the unit interval with grid size $\frac{1}{n}$.

Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-b}S_n=\frac{2}{5}$. If $b<0$, the limit of $S_n$ is clearly $0$ and if $b>0$, the limit is $\infty$. So $b$ must be $0$ and therefore $a=-\frac{5}{2}$.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!